# how to scp from a PC in a local network to my PC inside my local network?

Tags: networking, router, ssh, unix, scp

**CONTEXT**

- I have 2 PCs, **PC1** and **PC2**, both are in the same local
  network, **A**, and both use Unix

  - PC2 does stuff, and when it finishes, it transfers data to PC1 automatically via `scp` since PC1 & PC2 have fixed IPs within network A
  - I had to bring PC1 home and connect it to my local network, so I know my local IP (which is fixed until I reset the router).
- The router is from my ISP, so options are limited.

**QUESTION**

- I want to still transfer data automatically from PC2 to PC1, and if I do `scp`, I can put my public address, but that points to the router, and I need it to point towards PC1

  - How do you do this? I guess you need a tunnel, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You either have a ISP that gives you a public IP (IPv6 will do), or you need to pay your ISP to give you a public IP, or you need to pay a cloud hoster to give you a public IP (which you can then tunnel), or you can get a VPN into whatever network PC2 is on (probably you employer's, in which case he needs a public IP).

Comment: Provided you don't reboot your [home] modem, you should maintain the same WAN IP if your ISP doesn't assign you a static WAN IP, so the easiest way to accomplish this would be to create a DNAT rule [port forward] on the router, forwarding an arbitrary high WAN-side port >`50000` to the local IP of PC1 and the port PC1 uses to accept `scp` connections. PC2 would then `scp` to the WAN IP and WAN-side port configured in the DNAT rule, which should then successfully connect to PC1. _(The only caveat is if your ISP doesn't assign a static WAN IP, you may want to look into a DDNS subscription.)_

Comment: I create a virtual nertwork from my router following your comment (I found what you said is also called like that). I put as an example port 55000. Then I also opened this port in the router (just in case). Now I did from PC2: scp -P 55000 TEST.sh MYUSERNAME@MYPUBLICIP:/ but it gets like stuck, as if I would have to add something else to the command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngrok can help you set up a tcp tunnel which you can use to connect to your home PC.
Here's the link : https://ngrok.com/. It works with linux, windows and MacOS, choose your OS, download and sign up for an account on ngrok.
after installing, follow the instructions in : https://ngrok.com/docs#tcp to expose the ssh server on PC1:

```
./ngrok TCP 22
```

Forwarding tcp://1.tcp.ngrok.io:55147 -> localhost:22

Then on PC2:

```
scp your_files user@1.tcp.ngrok.io -p 55147
```

The free version of the software should be enough for your need.

Comment: It's a bit slow though, but it works! Thanks!

Just in case: User is the user from your PC. When you execute ./ngrok TCP 22 see the Forwarding line and modify both the adress and port for the line scp.

Comment: After a long time without using it, I just want to point out that: ./ngrok tcp 22 (tcp is in lower case) and: scp -P 55147 your_files local_user_PC@1.tcp.ngrok.io: